# mysql join is slow, but where is fast

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have 2 tables in a MySQL database. The 'results' table has ~6million rows, and contains 3 things: a value, an ID, and an ID of a result name in a different table. The 'result names' table contains about 2000 rows. Basically, the resultnames contain long strings which describe the results in the large table.

So, when I want to do a query, I'm simply joining the two tables so i know what the name of each result is.

The problem comes when I try to join the tables. If I do a join or a subquery like this, it's slow (join or subquery take approximately the same time):

```
mysql> select count(analysisresults_id) from analysis_results where result_nameid in (select resultname_id from analysis_resultnames where result_name like '%amygdala%');
+---------------------------+
| count(analysisresults_id) |
+---------------------------+
|                      6436 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (18.49 sec)
```

... but if I do the subquery separately it's *slightly* faster:

```
mysql> select count(analysisresults_id) from analysis_results where result_nameid in (13,28);
+---------------------------+
| count(analysisresults_id) |
+---------------------------+
|                      6436 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Why such a huge difference in the query times? And why is the subquery treated like a regular join?

Comment: What is the question? hardcode the values is faster. a big suprise.

Comment: `LIKE` is a slow comparison. You can negate some of that slowness by having an index on `result_name`, but it won't be as fast as directly referencing IDs

Comment: I'd agree the LIKE is slow, but it's only searching about 2000 rows, and running that query by itself is 0.01 sec

Comment: @GregB, the query you show above that takes 0.01 sec does not include a LIKE statement.  Can you show how long this query `select resultname_id from analysis_resultnames where result_name like '%amygdala%'` takes?

Comment: Hi @Lucas, `select resultname_id from analysis_resultnames where result_name like '%amygdala%'` takes 0.01 sec, so the total should be 0.02. Still less than 18sec :)

Comment: @GregB, I agree, it was just hard to determine that from the content of your question.  Looks like mister ExplosionPills has the right of it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't it do the subquery *first* and allow for use of the ID key?  Because it's a [`DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?115,128477,128477).

Even though the subquery does not actually seem to depend on the outer query, MySQL treats it like it is.  There are multiple solutions, and the easiest for you would probably just be to get the IDs ahead of time (since you've already done that).  It also seems like you could just use the same `WHERE` clause as the subquery.

Comment: wow, outstanding. I'm surprised by such a behaviour. I'm pretty sure oracle does not work like this. If it is so, now that's a (nother) huge difference between both rdbms.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Is there a way to make it an non-dependent query without using stored procedures?

Comment: @GregB not that I know of .. it's just the way MySQL seems to do things.  My second paragraph has some possible alternatives.  Using a single query is not always the best way

Comment: I found some more information about. It's considered a bug in the MySQL 5.x series, but it doesn't appear to be fixed: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25926

Comment: @GregB well that stinks; I've run into that same problem before.  Hopefully they will fix it at some point

Answer (score 0):

The string match is costly:

```
%amygdala%
```

Has to search every value *completely* (by completely, i mean it can short circuit on a match, but not on any non-match)

Comment: The second query still depends on the string match.  He does the string match to get the IDs in the first place.  His question is why a seeming equivalent takes so much longer.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, I follow what you are saying but dont read the OP that way.  The example code just shows how long the query takes when the ID's are used.  It does not show the composite time of running 2 separate queries. And his question was why one took so much longer than the other.

Comment: You should leave a comment on his question to clarify

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does a poor job of optimizing `in` subqueries, sometimes. Try this instead:

```
where exists (select 1
              from analysis_resultnames ar2
              where result_name like '%amygdala%' and
                    ar2.resultname_id = analysis_resultnames = resultname_id
             )
```

MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimizing-subqueries.html) is pretty clear that an uncorrelated subquery is evaluated exactly once.  This means that your original formulation is going to do a full table scan -- which is rather expensive.  This formulation *should* use the index to get the several thousand matching rows.  The additional `like` constraint should go pretty quickly on this subset.

As for the question about the subquery and the join.  You are confusing the database operation "join" with the keyword "join".  In SQL, there are several ways of expressing joins.  Some use keywords like "join" in the `from` clause.  Some use subqueries in the `where` and `select` (and even `having`) clauses.